# Array Dimension mismatch in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Why am I getting this error: the matrix `G` is of size 4x50 and I have left 2 dimensions free to accept the array?

> > Beta_Correlations;
> >     ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> Beta_Correlations at 28
         Correl_betas(j,k,l,:,:)=G;

```
Correl_betas=zeros(50,50,size(rates,1),4);
mats=[1:50]';
L1=-1;

for j=1:51
    L1=L1+1;
    L2=-1;
    for k=1:51
        L2=L2+1;
        for l=1:size(rates,1)


        y2=rates(l,mats2);

        yM=rates(l,:);


     dataList=struct('yM',yM,'mats',mats,'model',@NSS,'mats2',mats2,'y2',y2);
     lambda=[ L1; L2 ];   


    nObs=size(mats,1);
    G= [ones(nObs,1) (1-exp(-mats./lambda(1)))./(mats./lambda(1)) ((1-exp(-mats./lambda(1)))./(mats./lambda(1))-exp(-mats./lambda(1))) ((1-exp(-mats./lambda(2)))./(mats./lambda(2))-exp(-mats./lambda(2)))];




     Correl_betas(j,k,l,:,:)=G;
     check1=Correl_betas(1,1,1,:);
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a mismatch here

```
 Correl_betas=zeros(50,50,size(rates,1),4);  %4 par
 Correl_betas(j,k,l,:,:)=G;                  %5 par
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, I got it, just needed to asjust the number of array parameters!